# CSS Flexbox Button Layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

EDIT: Sorry. When I posted it last night, I forgot to include the code.

I have question regarding CSS Flexbox layout. You will see below both my html section and my css section. I am confused on what controls my button layout. You will see that the first four buttons are laid out in two rows and two columns. Then, buttons 5 and 6 are in one column, but two separate rows. Then, buttons 7 and 8 are one row, two columns. Then, the remainder of the buttons are all one column one row each.

[an image screenshot showing the button layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQfyZ.png)

You can see the live website by visiting [my GitHub Page](https://heathology.github.io/).

My question is this: What actually controls the layout of each button? What determines if it will be in two columns or one column?

I like alternating a one column, one row button every now and again, but I would like some consistency. Originally, I was trying to get 2-3 columns when the browser window is wide and when the browser window is smaller, like on a cellphone, it reduces down to one column.

Below is my html just for context. I was testing the different gradient classes. This is why you see btn-1 repeated everywhere, but in the CSS file I have 5 different buttons. Right now, that CSS only controls the gradient.

```
    <div class="btn-container">
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="cafe-menu/index.html">Cafe Menu</a>
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="registration-form/index.html">Registration Form</a>
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="survey-form/index.html">Survey Form</a> 
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="rothko-painting/index.html">CSS Rothko Painting</a> 
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="css-flexbox-photo-gallery/index.html">CSS Flexbox Photo Gallery</a>
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="css-nutrition-label/index.html">CSS Typography Nutrition Label</a>
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="html-css-quiz/index.html">HTML/CSS Quiz</a>
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="tribute-page/index.html">HTML/CSS Tribute Page</a> 
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="css-balance-sheet/index.html">HTML/CSS Balance Sheet</a> 
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="http://mettrys.com/" target="_blank">Mettry's WordPress Website</a>
        <a class="btn btn-1" href="http://circlea.co/" target="_blank">Circle A WordPress Website</a>
        <a class="btn btn-1"  href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/143444635/Website-WordPress-Graphic-Design" target="_blank">Other WordPress Websites</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS. This is where I have questions. It has to be the flexbox in either the .btn-container class or .btn class. It isn't the flex-direction or flex-wrap, is it?

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* logo */
.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 336px;
}

h1, p {
    text-align: center; 
}

/* Main Content Container */
.content {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 520px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .content {
        width: 50%;
      }
 
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .content {
      width: 50%;
    }

}

/* 2778x1284 pixels at 458ppi */
@media only screen 
    and (device-width: 428px) 
    and (device-height: 926px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

    }

/* Project Navigation Links */
.nav {
    text-align: center;
}

/* infinite gradient shift on hover buttons */

.btn-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 50vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .btn {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-size: 200% auto;
    color: white;
   /* text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 
rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #eee;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }

  /* <- buton css starts */

  .btn:hover {
    background-position: right center; /* 
change the direction of the change here */
  }

  .btn-1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to 
right, #60101D 20%, #2D2D82 50%, #60101D 
100%);
  }

  .btn-2 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to 
right, #60101D 0%, #2D2D82 50%, #60101D 
100%);
  }

  .btn-3 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to 
right, #60101D 0%, #2D2D82 50%, #60101D 
100%);
  }

  .btn-4 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to 
right, #60101D 0%, #2D2D82 50%, #60101D 
100%);
  }

  .btn-5 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to 
right, #60101D 0%, #2D2D82 50%, #60101D 
100%);
  }


  /* button css ends -> */

  a:link { text-decoration: none; }


a:visited { text-decoration: none; }


a:hover { text-decoration: none; }


a:active { text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text inside you button controls the layout. Rename button 5 to "Photo Gallery" and button 6 to "Nutrition Label" and you'll see they'll now sit side by side.

Once the screen size becomes smaller, all buttons comes to one column because you have used `flex-wrap: wrap` which means if no space found, the items will be placed under.

```
.btn-container {
  width: 50vw; // the container will have half the width of the screen
  display: flex; // flex will make all item sit side by side by default
  flex-wrap: wrap; // flex items to sit below prior flex items if no space in that row.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer makes sense. Besides shortening the names, do you have any recommendations on how I could do this better using flexbox? Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: @heathology using Flexbox, you cannot declared how many items will sit in one row, i.e. 2 items in a row equals 2 columns. Hence, I'll be using Grid as an alternative. 

So, I'd recommend you to see "CSS Grid layout" for Grid  & "CSS Media Queries" for managing CSS in small/big screen devices